# How to disable or move "Add to dictionary" in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, usability

I'm not the best speller and sometimes I miss when I click.  Consequently I'm constantly going to

```
chrome://settings/editDictionary
```

and clearing it out because I've accidently added a bit of nonsense that isn't a word.

[image]

Is there anyway to move the 'Add to dictionary' line away from the suggested words (even a horizontal rule would help), disable the custom dictionary, or am I doomed to a life of cleaning up after bad clicks?

Comment: This is one of the all-time worst UI decisions I've ever seen.  You put a minor, common action right next to a fairly rare action that has long-term effects and no confirmation.  Every few weeks I find that I've got a few misspellings to purge.